# Python and AT Commands

Tags: python, at-command

I need to send AT commands over ethernet to a device to configure it.  Here is what I have right now:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

host = "192.168.0.99"
port = 8080

msg = 'at\n'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(msg.encode())

data = s.recv(1024).decode()
print (data)
s.close()
```

I can putty to it, open a raw connection and it works.

[putty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt8Oj.png)

I type in "at", the controller echos "at" followed by an "ok" to acknowledge.

When I run the above script, I get "at" back.  Is it printing the echo and not the following line (the ok line) or is it just printing out the command I sent out?  How do I get it to read all the data that's received?

Comment: That `.recv()` is going to return as soon as *any* data is available from the device - that `1024` is a maximum amount it will return, not an amount that it will wait for.  If there is even a tiny delay between the echo and the command response, you're likely to get only the echo on the first call - and in fact, there's no guarantee that you'd even get the entire echo.  You need to call `.recv()` in a loop.

Comment: Makes sense.  So now I have this:

Comment: try to terminate your AT command with `\r\n`

Comment: Adding the \r\n worked!  What is \r?

Comment: \r - carrier return, \n - new line

Comment: \r\n (CR+LF) is the line ending in DOS/Windows environment. A lot of devices use that instead of the Unix/Linux world's \n (LF).

Comment: Regardless of what unix/dos/windows does, for *AT commands* the **only** relevant reference is the [V.250 standard](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). And it is leaves no room for doubt: "5.2.1 Command line general format": "A command line is made up of three elements: the prefix, the body, and the termination character." Notice here a *single termination character*, which value should be '\r' ("The termination character may be selected by a user option (parameter S3), the default being CR (IA5 0/13).").

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get it to read all the data that's received?

In general, after a program sends an AT command line to a modem, it should do absolutely nothing other than **reading and parsing** responses sent back from the modem until it receives a *Final result code*. The final result code indicates that the modem is finished processing the AT command line and is now ready to receive a new command line.

Your code for receiving data,

```
data = s.recv(1024).decode()
```

is just [picking up one single, arbitrary chunk of data sent over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976049/at-command-responses-understanding-order-of-code-execution-on-arduino/37977157#37977157) (which might be split up in a number of different ways). As [jasonharper already has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579800/python-and-at-commands#comment112429496_63579800), this must be done in a loop, specifically a [loop that checks for and wait till it receives a final result code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412250/how-in-codesys-call-an-at-command-for-gsm-modem-not-standart-send-sms-and-e-t/16446523#16446523).