# AT commands for HTTPS

Tags: http, post, https, get, at-command

I've been working with a SIM808 and sending HTTP GET requests using the following AT commands:

```
"AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\", 1\r\n"
"AT+HTTPINIT\r\n"
"AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://www.example.com/\"\r\n"
"AT+HTTPACTION=0\r\n"
"AT+HTTPREAD\r\n"
```

and it works fine . But when I replace the URL with `https`, I only receive `"OK"`

My question is if there is a way to use AT commands for `HTTPS` request methods (using SSL).

Comment: First, you should terminate an AT command line with only \r and nothing else, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21503919/23118).

Comment: Could you include the code you use to send commands/read responses?

Comment: @hlovdal I have been using \r\n for years and it has worked everytime. and the documentation of this module says specifically that the AT commands start and end with <CR><LF>

Comment: @hlovdal is the code really necessary? cause it's really long... I believe I'm receiving and sending everything correctly. my question is only if there is possible to send HTTPS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to execute `AT+HTTPSSL=1` after setting the URL. Hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks @Francisco,

How to pass a custom key via AT Command? I tried this way,

`AT+HTTPINIT`


`AT+HTTPPARA="URL","WWW.XYZ.COM"`


`AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"`


`AT+HTTPPARA="AuthenticationKey","mykey"` This line is not working.