# Extract UDP string from recieved packet (ESP8266)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, at-command

I am trying to use an ESP8266 to receive UDP packets and turn a specific LED using the UDP string received. I have made the Arduino program to get the UDP string and display it in the serial Monitor (BTW I want to use AT commands).

Here is a sample output:

```
+IPD,6:foobar
+IPD,6:foobar
+IPD,13:foobarhesbbdb
+IPD,13:foobarhesbbdb
```

**Problem:**

**Code**

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial softSerial(8, 9); // RX, TX
String line;
void setup() 
{
  uint32_t baud = 9600;

  Serial.begin(baud);
  softSerial.begin(baud);
  Serial.print("SETUP!! @");
  Serial.println(baud);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);


  softSerial.println("AT+CWJAP=\"***\",\"***\"");

 delay(1000);
  softSerial.write("\n");
  delay(2000);
 softSerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"UDP\",\"0\",0,5005,2\"\r");
 softSerial.write("\n");



}

void loop() 

{ 

    while(softSerial.available() > 0) 
    {
      char a = softSerial.read();
      if(a == '\0')
        continue;
      if(a != '\r' && a != '\n' && (a < 32))
        continue;
      Serial.print(a);

    }

        while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      char a = Serial.read();
      Serial.write(a);
      softSerial.write(a);
    }


}
```

How do I extract only the string without `+IPD,x`.
I'm new to ESP8266. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Arduino is not C. Don't spam tags.

Answer (score 0):

The (horribly) wrong thing you are doing is `delay`. To learn how to correctly extract only the string you are interested in, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064206/23118).

In addition, AT command lines should be terminated with exactly [only `\r`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21503919/23118) and not whatever `println` happens to use for EOL. So use `write` with an embedded `\r` at the end.