# Force 5G on SIM8200EA-M2

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, at-command, 5g

I've been having problems getting a 5G only connection using waveshares https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM8200EA-M2_5G_HAT for the raspberry pi.

Anyone know the the appropriate AT-commands ?

Answer (score 1):

I am also using this 5G module but with Jetson Nano and Windows. To force 5G, run this command.

```
AT+CNMP=71  //if your module green led turns off using this command, run the following command
AT+CNMP= 39 //AT command for 4G (LTE)
```

I never get 5G on my module.

Comment: I have a SIM8262E-M2 module now, still cannot get 5G

Comment: i was able to make it work. following the tutorial, the problem was in the port number, but i discovered it only on Windows PC, the USB port number was 9011, forcing it to the 9001 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about which access technology that is used with the `AT+CREG` network registration command (`AcT` parameter) and you can control which to used with the `AT+COPS` command.

In your case, the manufacturer documentation is linked as "SIm8200 Series AT Command Manual" on the wiki page you linked, and that should be your *primary* source of information. The commands are standardized by 3GPP in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) so you could have a look there as well.

PS Make sure you properly understand how to [send](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21503919/23118) and [**read and parse**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36899432/23118) AT command lines and response lines.