# GSM Modem not able to receive SMS

Tags: vb.net, at-command

i doing a simple application that able to integrate with GSM Modem to send and receive the SMS. i had completed the send SMS part, but i not able to receive the SMS. i get error message said that my SIM card memory is full when trying to send the SMS with other mobile device to my SIM card in the GSM Modem. i tried to use the AT command "AT+CMGL" to remove all the messages, but still same. May i know there are any method to store the message in my computer memory so that i able to receive the SMS with my GSM Modem. I using the sample code from here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code directly here in the question (even if it is exactly the same as found on some other web site - who knows how long that content will exists. And even if it lives as long as stackoverflow, clicking a link to get relevant information in questions is a barrier that should not exists).

Answer (score 0):

The `AT+CMGL` command is for listing messages, not deleting them. Deleting messages is done with the `AT+CMGD` command. Do yourself a favour and download a copy of the [3GPP 27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) standard, it defines all the standard sms AT commands (most other mobile phone AT commands are defined in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm)), and by all means get a copy of the ITU standard [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) which defines the basic command syntax, structure and behaviour for AT commands - an absolute must read for anyone that issues AT commands (read all of chapter 5 at least). These documents are more valuable than any random internet web site, including stackoverflow.

Speaking of random websites, the web page you linked as source seems to be of dubious value. It gives an example function `DeleteMsg` which issues `AT+CMGF=1` but this command does in no way delete anything, it selects text or PDU mode for the various sms related commands.

It does have response handling that is better than the horrible send-sleep-read mistake that unfortunately is not as uncommon as it ought to be, but it is only half decent and not robust at all.
After sending an AT command to a modem you should continuously read and parse response lines from the modem (over and over again) until you receive a final result code (and not just once). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) for details.

---

All of the the message commands operate on the storage location set by `AT+CPMS`. And notice that you should always set `<mem1>` and `<mem2>` at the same time, e.g.

```
AT+CPMS="SM","SM"
```

It both makes little sense to only change one of mem1/mem2, and some phones do not like attempts to set only one of them.