# time delay between AT commands for sending sms

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command

I am working on an application that sends SMS through GSM Modem, and i use AT Commands for that. **When i debug my application, Then sms is sent to reciever, but when i run the application sms is not sent to Reciever.**
My code is below and my gsm Modem is D-Link DWM-156.
is there any wrong here in my code?
thanks.

if (SPort.IsOpen)
            {

```
            int i = 0;
            while (i < msgs.Count)
            {
                SPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                var res = SPort.ReadExisting();
                SPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                SPort.Write("AT\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                while ((res = SPort.ReadExisting()).Contains("ERROR")) ;
                resultResponse += "1" + res + "---";

                SPort.Write("AT+CMGF=0\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                while ((res = SPort.ReadExisting()).Contains("ERROR")) ;
                resultResponse += "2" + res + "---";
                SPort.Write("AT+CSCS=\"HEX\"\r");//char set
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                while ((res = SPort.ReadExisting()).Contains("ERROR")) ;
                resultResponse += "3" + res + "---";

                SPort.Write("AT+CSMP=17,71,0,17\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                while ((res = SPort.ReadExisting()).Contains("ERROR")) ;
                resultResponse += "4" + res + "---";

                string hexString = msgs[i];

                SPort.Write(string.Format("AT+CMGS={0}\r", (hexString.Length - 16) / 2));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                while ((res = SPort.ReadExisting()).Contains("ERROR")) ;
                resultResponse += "5" + res + "---";

                SPort.Write(string.Format("{0}{1}\n", hexString, Convert.ToChar(26)));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                while ((res = SPort.ReadExisting()).Contains("ERROR")) ;
                resultResponse += "6" + res + "---";

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                response += res;
                i++;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there any wrong here in my code?

Yes, you need to rework your response handling a little bit, but you are actually close (and way better that the unfortunately not uncommon send-sleep pattern that I initially thought you were using when I saw a call to Sleep). And you are correctly using `\r` to terminate AT command lines, so good start.

After sending an AT command you should continuously read (over and over again) response lines from the modem until you get a Final result code (using 
`Contains("ERROR")` is not good enough). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) for the code flow structure and reference to a function for determining if a line is a final result code.

You can keep the 100ms delay between sending the command line and starting to read the response; I have in fact added 200ms to my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program recently (locally, not released yet).

And for the `AT+CMGS` command, you must wait until you have received the `"\r\n> "` string before sending any payload data (also covered in the answer linked above).

Comment: thanks for your useful answer, however i have not completed my program and i have the same problem.a question about you answer: if i receive an "ERROR" response, what should i do?? Should i resend the same command??  Should i cancel the same SMS commands and start it again??