# AT+CMGS doesn't work correctly

Tags: sms, at-command

I have a problem with AT command for sending SMS - `AT+CMGS`. After sending `AT+CMGS=<length of PDU datagram><CR>` I wait for response of modem. After reading `<CR><LF>><Space>` I send `<PDU datagram><CTRL-Z>` but I don't get any answer from modem. If I send any command after that the response to that command is `+CMGS=<reference number>` which is exactly the response which I expected later.

But if I wait for about 100ms after reading `<CR><LF>><Space>` and than send PDU datagram than everything works well and I receive expected answer from modem.

It is really necessary to wait after receiving response from modem? I thought that I can send response immediately after reading `<CR><LF>><Space>`. Can someone help me to understand where could be a problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What type of modem are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cinterion PLS8-E

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption, [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) states for `AT+CMGS`:

> the TA shall send a four character sequence
>   <CR><LF><greater_than><space> (IRA 13, 10, 62, 32) after command line
>   is terminated with <CR>; after that text can be entered from TE to
>   ME/TA.

(TA (terminal adapter) is modem, TE (terminal equipment) is sender of AT commands)

However, in practice [some additional small delay might be needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34251425/23118) even in cases where the modem have signalled that it is ready to receive.