# How do I fix HM-10 BLE module from returning odd characters?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno, at-command, hm-10

I am trying to send data to an Arduino via a HM-10 module(BLE) from a MacOS device and am following this [guide](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.15/doc/tutorials/programming/ble_duplex.html). For my wiring, I have done the following: I have the RX pin on the HM-10 hooked to the TX on the Arduino; the TX pin on the HM-10 to the RX on the Arduino; the VCC on the HM-10 to the 3.3V on the Arduino; the GND on the HM-10 to the GND on the Arduino.

I am using the following code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(0, 1); //RX|TX

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600); // default baud rate
  Serial.println("AT commands: ");
}

void loop(){
  //Read from the HM-10 and print in Serial Moniter
  if(BTSerial.available()) {
      Serial.write(BTSerial.read());
  }

  //Read from the Serial Moniter and print to the HM-10
  if(Serial.available()) {
      BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

When I send `AT+NAME?`, I should be receiving `OK+NAME:HMSoft`, but I keep on getting a string of odd characters: `AV⸮5⸮`. In addition, none of the commands seem to have any effect.

What am I doing wrong that I am unable to interact with the HM-10 from my computer?

Comment: Please note that despite the company claiming the HM-10 device supports AT commands, it does not (only something that vaguely resembles AT command). That protocol has several [severe flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35950215/23118), so you might want to look for alternative hardware.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(0, 1); //RX|TX
```

You are using hardware serial pins for software serial. And you are then using both, which corrupts the data.

Move the software serial pins to different ones, like 2 and 3.

Comment: I had already tried this before posting my question. When I type anything in the serial moniter, nothing returns. Any suggestions on what else I could do?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the pins to 2 and 3, choose Both NL&CR option to send commands to Arduino through the IDE. Otherwise it's not going to work.