# modem return ERROR for pdu

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command, pdu, smspdu

I'm sending this PDU to GSM modem and the modem returns

`ERROR
at+cmgs=70
0051000C918909414095640008A77E050003C8010106A9062F002006280627063206CC0627062806CC002006AF0630063106480627069806470020062D06A906450020062206460644062706CC0646000D000A064606270645002006A9062706310628063106CC003A0020006500780070006C006F00730069006F006E000D000A003900380035003300300030`

My modem is DWM-156(D-Link). This command works for other modems but not for DWM-156

I'm using this class to produce PDU strings:

```
SMSPDULib.SMS sms = new SMSPDULib.SMS();
sms.MessageEncoding = SMSPDULib.SMS.SMSEncoding.UCS2;  
sms.PhoneNumber = "+98" + to;
sms.Direction = SMSPDULib.SMSDirection.Submited;
sms.Message = text;
sms.ValidityPeriod = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
string[] pdus = sms.ComposeLongSMS();
WriteLintToModem("AT+CMGS=" + pdus[0].Length / 4 + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Should the last line be WriteLineToModem and not WriteLintToModem?

Comment: You should not use `Environment.NewLine` to terminate AT command lines, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) for details. Not sure if this your main problem, but it is definitely wrong and should be fixed.