# Recieving Blank SMS SIM800 using AT Commands and Python on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gsm, at-command

I created this python script on rpi2, the message goes through, but it is a blank message. Is it a encoding issue?

```
import serial
import time
from sys import version_info
from curses import ascii
phone = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200, timeout=0.5)
def send_text(number,message):    
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGS="' + number.encode() + b'"\r')
    phone.write(message.encode())
    phone.write(ascii.ctrl('z'))
    for i in range(len(reply)):
        reply[i] = reply[i].rstrip()
    print reply
```

AT commands (where 0000000000 is a 10 digit mobile number)
in Minicom, still **blank** message

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 115200 -o

AT
OK
AT+CMGS="0000000000"
>Hello
 <ctrl-z>
+CMGS: 14
OK
```

[Screenshot of Message from GSM Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Pr4.png)

Comment: You are properly terminating the AT command line correctly  with `\r`, good. But you should **never, never, ever use sleep as a substitute for waiting for the Final result code from the modem.** See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) for details. Without fixing that you will never get any of your AT command code to behave reliably.

Comment: Ya thanks for that! Ill fix that code! Though the above problem was solved by this AT command   `AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with the **text mode** parameters. The AT command below fixed it -

```
AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0

--info about it
AT+CSMP=<fo>,<vp>,<pid>,<dcs>
<fo>=17 Sets reply pat, user data header, status report request, validity period format, reject duplicates and message type.
<vp>=167 Sets validity period.
<pid>=0 Higher layer protocol indicator.
<dcs>=0 Information encode format.
OK Modem Response.
```

Comment: Hi, what CSCS setting was used with this? I tried this, but it didn't work for me. This works if I send the data from a serial port utility, but not from the device firmware (Texas Instrument Launchpad).

Comment: Thank you mate .. your answer helped me in another issue rather than the question it self.  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0

Parameters
 Depending on the command or result code: first octet of GSM
03.40 SMS-DELIVER, SMS-SUBMIT (default 17),

SMS-STATUS-REPORT, or SMS-COMMAND (default 2) an integer
format. SMS status report is supported under text mode if  is set to 49.

Depending on SMS-SUBMIT  setting: GSM 03.40
TP-Validity-Period either in integer format (default 167) or in time-string
format (refer )

GSM 03.40 TP-Protocol-Identifier in integer format (default 0).

GSM 03.38 SMS Data Coding Scheme in Integer format.