# AT commands on the Mobile phone

Tags: gsm, at-command, gprs, mobile-phones

What tasks can be accomplished using AT commands? Is it possible to get current status of the phone, the manufacturer and few other details linked to mobile phone?

Comment: Yes.Google for *gsm AT command set*.

Comment: All the commands in Abhimanyu Efy's answer are defined in either the [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) standard or the [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) standard. You should read both of those documents, they are [important standards](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118).

Answer (score 5):

I Found your answer on this [GSM module](http://electronicsforu.com/resources/what-is-gsm-module) article.

- Get basic information about the mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem. For example, name of manufacturer (AT+CGMI), model number (AT+CGMM), IMEI number (International Mobile Equipment Identity) (AT+CGSN) and software version (AT+CGMR).
- Get basic information about the subscriber. For example, MSISDN (AT+CNUM) and IMSI number (International Mobile Subscriber Identity) (AT+CIMI).
- Get the current status of the mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem. For example, mobile phone activity status (AT+CPAS), mobile network registration status (AT+CREG), radio signal strength (AT+CSQ), battery charge level and battery charging status (AT+CBC).
- Establish a data connection or voice connection to a remote modem (ATD, ATA, etc).
- Send and receive fax (ATD, ATA, AT+F*).
- Send (AT+CMGS, AT+CMSS), read (AT+CMGR, AT+CMGL), write (AT+CMGW) or delete (AT+CMGD) SMS messages and obtain notifications of newly received SMS messages (AT+CNMI).
- Read (AT+CPBR), write (AT+CPBW) or search (AT+CPBF) phonebook entries.
- Perform security-related tasks, such as opening or closing facility locks (AT+CLCK), checking whether a facility is locked (AT+CLCK) and changing passwords (AT+CPWD).
  (Facility lock examples: SIM lock [a password must be given to the SIM card every time the mobile phone is switched on] and PH-SIM lock [a certain SIM card is associated with the mobile phone. To use other SIM cards with the mobile phone, a password must be entered.])
- Control the presentation of result codes / error messages of AT commands. For example, you can control whether to enable certain error messages (AT+CMEE) and whether error messages should be displayed in numeric format or verbose format (AT+CMEE=1 or AT+CMEE=2).
- Get or change the configurations of the mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem. For example, change the GSM network (AT+COPS), bearer service type (AT+CBST), radio link protocol parameters (AT+CRLP), SMS center address (AT+CSCA) and storage of SMS messages (AT+CPMS).
- Save and restore configurations of the mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem. For example, save (AT+CSAS) and restore (AT+CRES) settings related to SMS messaging such as the SMS center address.