# AT Command: USSD

Tags: android, at-command, ussd

I am trying to make `USSD` call to send `AT` command. When I execute code, I get following error:

> "Error running exec(). Command: [AT+CUSD=1,"*222#",15] Working Directory: null Environment: null"

My code is:

```
String args="AT+CUSD=1,\"*222#\",15";
try {
     java.lang.Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
     Log.e("zoraf",bufferedReader.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What can be done to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It seams that you lack some basic understanding of what AT commands are and how they operate. AT commands are not something that you pass to a shell or the operating system like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args)` implies. AT commands are text command that you send to a modem over a serial interface (e.g. USB, Bluetooth, RS-232 or a virtual one).

The absolutely best place for you to start is to read all of chapter 5 of the [V.250 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). It is an [extremely important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) document that will guaranteed teach you much more about AT commands than you currently know.