# read sms message from modem using AT command in c#

Tags: c#, at-command, modem

I'm trying to show sms messages in modem (I use my phone as modem),
Port connect successfully by using AT commands
and I can Import the number and date but the body of message show as number.
this is my code :

```
port.Write("AT" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        port.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        port.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"\r" + System.Environment.NewLine); //("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\"\r");          
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        MessageBox.Show(port.ReadExisting());
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzCvh.png these is the result]

Comment: That looks like PDU so AT+CMGF=1 is being ignored, ensure the modem issues an OK in response to it.

Comment: I write these line

Comment: Virtually [the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33234810/23118) has been asked before. Everything I wrote in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) applies to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to send SMS through C# code using System.IO.Ports using gsm modem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234810/unable-to-send-sms-through-c-sharp-code-using-system-io-ports-using-gsm-modem)