# Why C# Serial port not working with AT+CGSN

Tags: c#, serial-port, at-command

Im trying to get IMEI of a Samsung S7 device.  I tried with `AT+CGSN` via `Putty` which worked perfectly.  When I tried the same with C# `SerialPort` returns empty string.

Sending AT\r\n on C# `SerialPort`  giving "OK" as expected and all other AT commands are also working except this

It looks bit wired for me on why it was not working for the specific commands where others are working.

Here is the sample.

```
  private static string GetMobileSerialNumber(string PortName)
    {
        string Serial = "";
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
        serialPort.PortName = PortName;
        serialPort.BaudRate = 154200;
        serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 16384;         
        try
        {
            if (!(serialPort.IsOpen))
                serialPort.Open();               
            serialPort.Write("AT+CGSN\r\n");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Serial = serialPort.ReadExisting();



            serialPort.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(Serial);

            return Serial;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Error in opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Sample also available [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/583315/Using-SerialPort-and-AT-Commands-for-Querying-Cell)

Comment: Try only writing "AT\r\n" to the SerialPort first, maybe it needs this as some sort of primer

Comment: If you are using same baud rate as putty, then the issue must be the PortName.  Make sure the port name is exactly same as putty.

Comment: @MindSwipe AT\r\n giving "OK" as expected and all other AT commands are also working except this.

Comment: @jdweng  Configuration is same as putty and commands like AT\r\n response "OK" as expected and all other AT commands are also working except this.

Comment: I just can think of a timing issue. Maye it takes more than 1 Second to respond to `AT+CGSN`. You can try to increase the `Thread.Sleep` or do a loop until `OK` is part of the result.

Comment: @GWimpassinger , I.m pretty much sure that this isn't timing issue as putty takes less than 500ms.  anyway, I tried even 10 secs but response is empty..

Comment: AT commands only require the carriage return character ("\r") on sending, it is possible the linefeed ("\n") is aborting the reply. See if "AT+CGSN\r" works.

Comment: PaulF is right in that `\r` is the only correct command line termination character. You will learn this by reading the V.250 specification. And by all means, **[you should never use `Thread.sleep` as a substitute for reading and parsing the responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064206/23118)**. Please update your code accordingly and then see if you still have problems.

Comment: @PaulF , thanks for the sugesstion, I tried the same with "AT+CGSN\r" still response is same as empty string

Comment: Possibly try writing each char at a time (like typing in a terminal program like Putty).  Maybe sending it all as one string is throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY and teraterm filtering /n /r similar parameters CR LF byte commands.

your cmd wrong