# HTTP Error When trying to send data from arduino to sql server. +HTTPACTION: 0,301,305

Tags: c, arduino, at-command

I'm trying to send data from Arduino to my server using get method.
Using sim800L & Arduino Nano through AT Commands.

```
GSM_serial.print("+++");
updateSerial();
delay(1000);
GSM_serial.print("AT\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(1000);
GSM_serial.print("ATE1\r\n"); 
updateSerial();
delay(1000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+CGATT=1\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(1000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(1000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"");
updateSerial();
GSM_serial.print(AccessPointName);
updateSerial();
GSM_serial.print("\"\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(1000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+SAPBR=1,1\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(3000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+HTTPINIT\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(1000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(2000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"");
GSM_serial.print(HTTPserver);// defined above as #define HTTPserver 
"http://--------.me"
GSM_serial.print(HTTPurl);//defined above as #define HTTPurl "/d.php?"
GSM_serial.print(message);// message is i=1&f=2
// total url is http://---------.me/d.php?i=1&f=2
GSM_serial.print("\"\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(2000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+HTTPACTION=0\r\n");
updateSerial();
delay(6000);
GSM_serial.print("AT+HTTPTERM\r\n");
updateSerial();
```

Result in serial Monitor:

```
AT
OK
ATE1
OK
AT+CGATT=1
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","touch"
OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1
OK
Connected
AT+HTTPINIT
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://system.fabricaid.me/d.php?i=1&f=2"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK
+HTTPACTION: 0,603,0
AT+HTTPTERM
OK
AT+S
```

---

Expected HTTP Action should be 200 instead of 603

```
+HTTPACTION: 0,603,0
```

Comment: There's no standard `603` HTTP return codes. Perhaps you should take a look at what happens on the server? Or read the documentation of the modem if it's the modem that replies with the 603 error?

Comment: You should [never, never, never ever use `delay` like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064206/23118). TL;DR: You must **read and parse** everything the modem sends back to you. **Nothing else will work reliably**.

Comment: @Hussam Did you have success when you changed to **reading and parsing** responses from the modem? Could you update the code in the question?

Comment: In the SIM800 documentation, the 603 code corresponds to DNS Error. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape both **?** and **&**. The whole URL should be

```
GSM_serial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://system.fabricaid.me/d.php\?i=1\&f=2\"");
```