# Arduino UNO + SIM800L - sending data to server

Tags: c++, arduino, at-command, arduino-c++, sim800

I am using arduino UNO board, with modem sim800l. I want use it to send data to server mysql every 10 seconds.  Everything is working fine when I have serial monitor open in arduino IDE (data is being saved to the mysql database)but when serial monitor is off then does not work.

I want use my system remote, connected to the powerbank. But it works only when I have opened arduino IDE serial monitor.

How to edit the code so that the microcontroller works without connecting to a computer and an open serial monitor?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7, 8);

void setup()
{
  gprsSerial.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(19200);

  Serial.println("Config SIM900...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Done!...");
  gprsSerial.flush();
  Serial.flush();

  // attach or detach from GPRS service 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(100);
  toSerial();


  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
}


void loop()
{
   // initialize http service
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
   delay(2000); 
   toSerial();

   // set http param value
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://server.net/test.php?data1=2&data2=3\""); 
   delay(2000);
   toSerial();

   // set http action type 0 = GET, 1 = POST, 2 = HEAD
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   delay(6000);
   toSerial();

   // read server response
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD"); 
   delay(1000);
   toSerial();

   gprsSerial.println("");
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
   toSerial();
   delay(300);

   gprsSerial.println("");
   delay(10000);
}

void toSerial()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  {
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: You already have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899238/how-to-write-code-to-work-without-viewing-the-serial-monitor-arduino-at-comman) open. Edit it instead of asking a new one. (or at least delete that one!)

Comment: The language you're using here is C++ with no C++ standard library. The C tag doesn't apply at all.

Comment: [Please stop using `delay` like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064206/23118). You must **read** and **parse** the responses received from the modem.

Comment: @RichardChambers Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I am very grateful for that. Tomorrow I will work on it and let you know if it worked. I haven't used your advice yet but for now I know that after pressing the RESET button on the arduino UNO microcontroller the system starts and works but sometimes it stops and does not work without pressing the RESET button again.

Comment: Hmmm. That behavior does lend support to the idea that something in your program is running into a wait state due to needing some resource. The RESET button restarts the system and your program is then free to run until it once more needs some resource and needs to wait until it is available. I suspect in your case the resource is serial output buffer space due to no device consuming the characters from the serial port. I'm curious as to how large is the serial output buffer and how many bytes are you writing out. Could you print the value of `Serial.availableForWrite()` in `Setup()`?

Comment: @RichardChambers OK, I start working on it again. I noticed that while powering up the modem needs time to catch a signal. About 10 seconds. In the SETUP function, I added DELAY 20000 to modem haev a time to catch the signal. And now after turning the power on do not need to press the RESET button for the program to start working. I am testing it now and now working one hour without interruption. When I added 'Serial.availableForWrite()' then print out: **63**.

Comment: Before disconnected because maybe the connection on the electric wires was disturbed.

Comment: So I can say that it works for me. Now I have to add 4 digital DS18B20 temperature sensors to the system. And send data from the sensors via the GSM network. Now it is set rigidly here `gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://server.net/test.php?data1=2&data2=3\""); `

Comment: @RichardChambers I think that instead of the DELAY function at the beginning it would be better to add some checking if there is a network connection. If yes then can start working.. Because the danger is that, what if the GSM signal is lost? The program will stop working again.

Comment: As pointed out in a comment above, using a `delay()` the way you are doing is not a robust and reliable way of waiting for something to happen. And the error checking that you are doing is non-existent which also leads to unreliable and non-robust programs. Unfortunately the real world is a messy place and equipment fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the underlying implementation of `Serial` however there may be some kind of an infinite wait for the `Serial.println()` that is happening.

And reading the documentation on `Serial.flush()` it appears that it may also be the cause of an infinite wait for the serial output to finish before it returns.

Since `Serial.println()` seems to use the `Serial.write()` functionality to do its thing I would suppose that if you have no device reading from the serial port at some point the write buffer is getting full and causing the `Serial.println()` to block. See https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/

> Notes and Warnings
>
> As of Arduino IDE 1.0, serial transmission is asynchronous. If there
>   is enough empty space in the transmit buffer, Serial.write() will
>   return before any characters are transmitted over serial. If the
>   transmit buffer is full then Serial.write() will block until there is
>   enough space in the buffer. To avoid blocking calls to Serial.write(),
>   you can first check the amount of free space in the transmit buffer
>   using availableForWrite().

See this explanation of the `Serial.flush()` function https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/flush/ which notes:

> Serial.flush()
>
> Description
>
> Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete. (Prior
>   to Arduino 1.0, this instead removed any buffered incoming serial
>   data.)
>
> flush() inherits from the Stream utility class.

And see this article, https://www.baldengineer.com/when-do-you-use-the-arduinos-to-use-serial-flush.html which says"

> What does Serial.flush() do?
>
> From the Arduino reference for Serial.flush (found on this page):
>
> > Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete.
>
> The key to that statement is “outgoing”.   Serial.flush() doesn’t
>   empty the “incoming” buffer as many people think.  It pauses your
>   program while the transmit buffer is flushed.

I would use the `Serial.availableForWrite()` function before doing any output using `Serial.println()` and if the number of bytes available indicates that the write buffer is getting full then skip the output.

Probably the best approach would be as part of the `Setup()` function to check the write buffer size after doing the `Serial.begin()` and store that in a global variable which you then use to check to see if the write buffer is getting emptied or not.

See https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Serial/ which has this to say:

> Step 3: Command : ​ AvailableForWrite()
>
> Description
>
> Get the number of bytes (characters) available for writing in the
>   serial buffer without blocking the write operation.
>
> Syntax
>
> Serial.availableForWrite()

See also https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/availableforwrite/

There is also `if (Serial)` which can be used to check if the port is available. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/ifserial/  however I suspect that it is more of a check that the requested port is available rather than whether the port is actually functioning with a device on the other end of the link.

And there is also the `Serial.available()` https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/

> Serial.available()
>
> Description
>
> Get the number of bytes (characters) available for reading from the
>   serial port. This is data that’s already arrived and stored in the
>   serial receive buffer (which holds 64 bytes).
>
> Serial.available() inherits from the Stream utility class.
>
> Syntax
>
> Serial.available()
>
> Parameters
>
> Serial: serial port object. See the list of available serial ports for
>   each board on the Serial main page.
>
> Returns
>
> The number of bytes available to read.

**Suggested course of action**

First of all, I don't see that the `Serial.flush()` in the `Setup()` function is necessary and it could be safely removed. While this makes the console output immediate during the `Setup()` it does introduce a wait for the remote case in which there is no device reading from the serial line to empty the output buffer.

I also suggest that for each line you do `Serial.println()` you do a check on the number of bytes of buffer available with `Serial.availableForWrite()` first as in:

```
int firstAvailableForWrite = 0;

void Setup ()
{
    // set up everything you do then add the following statement
    firstAvailableForWrite = Serial.availableForWrite();
}
```

Then where ever you are going to do a write modify that with an `if` statement similar to the following example:

```
if (Serial.availableForWrite() >= firstAvailableForWrite) Serial.println("Config SIM900...");
```

Or you could also create a function something like the following:

```
int serialPrintLineIfAvailable (char *aszLine)
{
    int iCount = 0;
    if (Serial.availableForWrite() >= firstAvailableForWrite) iCount = Serial.println(aszLine);

    return iCount;
}
```

Then wherever you want to use `Serial.println()` you would instead use `serialPrintLineIfAvailable()` as in `serialPrintLineIfAvailable("Config SIM900...");`