# Stop getting response from LTE module using AT command

Tags: gsm, at-command, lte, sim900

When the number is dialed from any of the number to LTE module, I got automatic responses from that module for e.g.

`[2018-07-02 15:43:30:997_R:] DSR:0 CTS:1 (RI:0) DCD:0
 [2018-07-02 15:43:30:997_R:] DSR:0 CTS:1 (RI:1) DCD:0
 [2018-07-02 15:43:31:012_R:] NO CARRIER`   .
 These are autogenerated responses without firing AT commands to the module. So I 
  don't want these responses. Please suggest me any AT command to stop this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These responses are called `unsolicited result codes` because they are triggered by events other than AT commands.

To learn more about the different types of responses read chapter `5.7.1 Responses` in the [ITU V.250 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). V.250 is one of [the most important AT command documents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) and you should really read all of chapter 5.

Some of the unsolicited result codes can be individually disabled, but some (e.g. `NO CARRIER`) cannot, so you must write your modem software to handle them. There is no way around.