# AT-Commands (Python) SMS Length Issue

Tags: python-3.x, at-command

I am using AT-Commands in Python3 to send SMS using my GSM Module. Maximum length of single SMS is 160 Characters only. I need more than it. The SMS having the contents of length more than it are NOT sent at all.

I need to send SMS of 250 length (for example). Please help me to overcome this problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A sms message has a hard upper limit of 160 characters, however it is possible to combine several sms messages into a "virtual" message that then appears to be longer. The technical name for this is **multi-part**, e.g. combining several sms messages into one virtual larger message.

Sending sms messages with AT commands can be done in two ways, **text mode** and **pdu mode** and notice that **text mode** only supports sending single sms messages; in order to send a multi-part message you must use **pdu mode**.

---

And to preempt any poor AT command handling, remember that you must [wait for the ready to receive data prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) before sending the sms payload, and in general [read and parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) response lines from the modem waiting for the final result code.