# What's the escape character in AT-commands?

Tags: mqtt, at-command, modem, firmware, nb-iot

Im using a BG96 modem to connect to AWS iot over MQTT.

I'm trying to set my MQTT Last Will and Testament with the following AT-command:

```
+QMTCFG:"will",(0-5),(0,1),(0-2),(0,1),"willtopic","willmessage"
```

Which works great. 
But now I'm trying to add a JSON formatted string to `"willmessage"`, so I need to add `""` (double quotes) in there, which means I need to escape them in my command. But I have no clue if I can escape them or what the escape character is.

Things I tried: `\"` (backslash) and `""` (double double quotes)

I looked in all of the BG96 datasheets, and I don't see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: did you try with ***"{'key':'value'}"*** ???

Comment: Forgive my basic question, but what happens if you simply add the inner double quotes without escaping them?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Single quotes work, but isn't valid JSON, so it's not recognized by AWS on the other side.

Comment: @000 the input cuts off. For example `+QMTCFG:"will",0,0,0,0,"test\topic","{"key":"value"}"` will result in a message with a single `{` in it on the other side.

Comment: Ok, I see. It's something very implementation dependant. Other devices, as far as I know, have different behavior. Or at least designed an _online_interface for binary data (including special chars like `"`). One last attempt: could you try escaping the hex ASCII value with `\x22`?

Comment: @000 no difference between `\x22` and actual quotes `"`.

Comment: @000 if I actually include `\x22` in the message as text that gets send to AWS, it also doesn't get translated to `"` by AWS. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using MQTT commands on a SIMCOM SIM800c, and I noticed that the regular backslash (\) escapes the quotation marks (as it does in c) when communicating directly with the GSM unit via a USB to TTL converter. To implement this in software I printed the following string to the UART connected to the GSM Modem:

```
AT+SMPUB=\"testTopicPost\",0,1,\"{\x5c\x22Key\x5c\x22 : \x5c\x22Value\x5c\x22}\"
```

What this basically does is send the raw \ and " characters to the GSM unit. Hope this solution works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but looks like this isn't the case for the BG96

Answer (score 0):

Escaping of `"` within a string is covered in chapter *5.4.2.2 String constants* in the [V.250 standard](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) - which is a [**MUST READ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) for anyone writing code handling AT commands (read at least all of chapter 5):

> String constants shall consist of a sequence of ... except for the characters """ ... . String constants shall be bounded at the beginning and end by the double-quote character (""" ... . ... The double-quote character, used as the beginning and ending string delimiter, shall be represented within a string constant as "\22".

So the escape mechanism is `\22` not `\x22`. This should be universally the case for all modems and not something that is implementation dependent.

I did not find reference to documentation of MQTT and BG96 and you did not link any of your "all of the BG96 datasheets" so I am just providing example syntax for an imaginary command to send a JSON payload of `{"key": "value"}`:

```
AT+SOMECOMMAND=...,"{\22key\22: \22value\22}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some special characters have different values between the ASCII character set and the GSM character set.

i.e.

- In the ASCII character set: `\` = 0x5C.
- In the GSM character set: `Ö` = 0x5C.

Beyond this point, some special characters must be entered using a specific way, such as a 2-byte representation. I suggest you check the standard/version of AT commands implemented on your hardware (i.e. GSM 07.07, GSM 07.05, manufacturer specific set...).

i.e. I'm using a GPS+GPRS modem from Ai-Thinker called A9G. In this one, to use the AT+MQTTPUB command with data formatted in JSON style, I need to append `\x5c\x32\x32`. So the module will interpret this as `\22` and the server as `\"`.

i.g.

```
"{\x5c\x32\x32Key\x5c\x32\x32:\x5c\x32\x32Value\x5c\x32\x32}"
```

at the cloud it will be:

```
{"Key":"Value"}
```